# Queries not working in a function within Laravel, but works in other places

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a function that looks like this:

```
  public function update() {
      $reports = Reports::find(1);
      return $reports;
  }
```

This function however is not returning anything. The reports table however does has an element with a pkey of 1:

```
INSERT INTO `theDatabase`.`reports` (`pkey`, `id`, `comment`, `youtubeUrl`, `displayName`, `profilePictureUrl`, `approvalStatus`, `rep`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (1, '1234567890', 'This is just a test report', 'https://example.com', 'Test User', 'https://example.com/somethingsomething', '0', '1', '2015-02-22 00:00:00', '2015-02-22 00:00:00')
```

And if within this same function I instead do a `::all` I get this response:

```
[{"pkey":1,"id":"1234567890","comment":"This is just a test report","youtubeUrl":"https:\/\/youtube.com\/watch?32222","displayName":"Test User","profilePictureUrl":"https:\/\/google.com\/somethingsomething","approvalStatus":0,"rep":1,"created_at":"2015-02-22 00:00:00","updated_at":"2015-02-22 00:00:00"},{"pkey":4,"id":"12345678903","comment":"This is just a test report","youtubeUrl":"https:\/\/youtube.com\/watch?32222","displayName":"Test User","profilePictureUrl":"https:\/\/google.com\/somethingsomething","approvalStatus":1,"rep":1,"created_at":"2015-02-22 00:00:00","updated_at":"2015-02-22 00:00:00"}]
```

That is with this code:

```
  public function update() {
      $reports = Reports::all();
      return $reports;
  }
```

So I am a little confused here why this is not working correctly. Also; another function within the controller is using a query and it has no troubles returning the correct output. This is the code of the other function:

```
 public function index() {
      $reports = Reports::all()->where('approvalStatus', '=', 0);

      return view('reports.index', compact('reports'));
  }
```

I am wondering what I am doing incorrectly here? As a side note, this is being called via a post request with a route that looks like this:

```
Route::post('reports/update', 'ReportsController@update');
```

Doubt that matters, but extra information doesn't hurt.

Doing a `dd($reports)` after the `::find(1)` returns the following output:

```
undefined: {undefined: -909362565, " ": null}
" ": null
undefined: -909362565
```

Edit for comment:

```
  $reports = Reports::where("pkey",1);
  dd($reports);
  return $reports;
```

Getting this:

```
ErrorException in Response.php line 406:
Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string

0: {undefined: {undefined: 2,…}, Protected property: false}
Protected property: false
undefined: {undefined: 2,…}
Protected property: " class=sf-dump-note>Application</abbr> {<a class=sf-dump-ref href=#sf-dump-748334229-ref22 title="
undefined: 2
1: 3
2: {undefined: 2,…}
3: "Protected property"
4: false
```

Comment: What dd($reports) shows?

Comment: Is ID field an integer field?

Comment: @Boris added the `dd` output to the OP. `id` relates to the column `pkey` in the table which is an incremental column. Id itself is passed via a post request

Comment: change find(1) with where('id', 1) and test. Those quotes around ID in ""pkey":1,"id":"1234567890"" makes me think its a char and thats why it fails to find any results

Comment: @Boris I don't believe where can be used in the static context: `Reports::where` is not a method.

Comment: You are right, use Reports::where('id', 1)->firstOrFail();

Comment: @Boris I am using Laravel 5. Doing `Reports::where("id", 1)->firstOrFail()` does not work. `where` is not part of a models static declaration. I would have to do something like `Reports::all()->where()`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Not really sure about changes in L5, according to the documentation it should work, however try what you proposed.

Comment: @Boris I have tried your way and have put the dd($reports) output in the OP again.

Comment: I believe I got confused, you are searching by pkey in where(), but find() uses field with name "id" to work as far as i know.

Comment: @Boris The field in the table that is the primary key is named `pkey`. That `id` value being passed via a post request is just an incorrect name. It should be `pkey`, I just had not changed it in the code. I am just simply trying to find the record associated with the pkey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eloquent uses by default `id` as primary key and `find` method is looking record by primary key. However you can change your primary key name if you have different schema. In `Eloquent` model you can specify:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'pkey';
```

and now `find` will use `pkey` as primary key.

You can also set manually your table name in case if it were not `reports` but for example `reporting_system`:

```
protected $table = 'reporting_system';
```

Comment: Thanks this was the problem, and fixed the issue. I instead altered the table and no sense going back to this, however this is definitely the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I altered my schema so that `pkey` is now named `id`, and my old `id` column is now named `profileId`. I guess `find()` is using `id` as the primary key field.

Comment: I tried to simulate your case, and the pkey does not seems to be problem, it works perfectly here. Maybe the declaration of the pkey in the Model?

Comment: @Boris I am not sure why it was not working, however I just know these changes made have fixed the issue.